# Setting width in C++ output stream

Tags: c++, width

I'm trying to create a neatly formatted table on C++ by setting the width of the different fields. I can use setw(n), doing something like

```
cout << setw(10) << x << setw(10) << y << endl;
```

or change ios_base::width

```
cout.width (10);
cout << x;
cout.width (10);
cout << y << endl;
```

The problem is, neither of the alternatives allows me to set a default minimum width, and I have to change it everytime I'll write something to the stream.

Does anybody knows a way I can do it without having to repeat the same call countless times?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective use of C++ iomanip library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328411/effective-use-of-c-iomanip-library) or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405039/permanent-stdsetw

Comment: Related to the stickiness of various iomanip manipulators. setw is NOT sticky: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have looked for something similar before, but without success. The answers here and in the others posts gave me a good grasp of how I can solve it, thanks.

Comment: If you can, you should use _Boost.Format_. Look at the [answer from Herb Sutter to the question 'C++ alignment when printing cout <<'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485963/c-alignment-when-printing-cout/2486085#2486085)

Comment: A work round is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37495361/984471

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create an object that overloads `operator<<` and contains an `iostream` object that will automatically call `setw` internally.  For instance:

```
class formatted_output
{
    private:
        int width;
        ostream& stream_obj;

    public:
        formatted_output(ostream& obj, int w): width(w), stream_obj(obj) {}

        template<typename T>
        formatted_output& operator<<(const T& output)
        {
            stream_obj << setw(width) << output;

            return *this;
        }

        formatted_output& operator<<(ostream& (*func)(ostream&))
        {
            func(stream_obj);
            return *this;
        }
};
```

You can now call it like the following:

```
formatted_output field_output(cout, 10);
field_output << x << y << endl;
```

Comment: +1, thanks! In case anyone else is interested: the second `operator<<` defined above allows the class to deal with functions such as `std::endl`, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134388/stdendl-is-of-unknown-type-when-overloading-operator). Hope this helps any other curious cats who are picking apart @Jason's code...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is still making the same call, but I know of no other solution from what I am getting from your question.

```
#define COUT std::cout.width(10);std::cout<<

int main()
{
    std::cout.fill( '.' );

    COUT "foo" << std::endl;
    COUT "bar" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
..........foo
..........bar
```

Comment: Why use macro if a template can be easily made and even allows chaining of output?

Answer (score 0):

why not just create a function?

pseudocode e.g.

```
void format_cout(text, w) {
 cout << text << width(w);
}
```

That's a bit scrappy but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: This approach is nice and simple, but it wouldn't let you use chained `operator<<s`. It would also cause (whitespace) problems when you try to use `std::endl`...