# How to allow setw apply to all the following stdout?

Tags: c++

Should be a trivial question, but found that setw only apply to its immediate following output, and not sure how to allow it apply to all the following output.

For example, for the following line of code

```
cout<<setw(3)<<setfill('0')<<8<<" "<<9<<endl;
```

or

```
cout.width(3);
cout.fill('0');
cout<<8<<" "<<9<<endl;
```

I want the output to be `008 009` instead of `008 9`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which iomanip manipulators are 'sticky'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky)

Comment: Printing `" "` with width 3 would output 3 spaces, or even `"00 "`

Comment: Or duplicate of [Setting width in C++ output stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248627/setting-width-in-c-output-stream).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setw` isn't sticky, so you have to say it every time:

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(3) << 8 << " "
     << setw(3) << 9 << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Use proxy struct for this.

```
struct setw_all_the_way {
    template <typename T> std::ostring &operator << (T &&t) {
        return std::cout << std::setw(14) << std::forward<T>(t);
    }
};
setw_all_the_way << ...;
```