# Using the iomanip directive

Tags: c++, iomanip

I know how to set field width but only applying to the first element in the stream.
For example.

```
cout << setw(5) << left << '1' << '2';
```

produces

```
1     2
```

and

```
cout << setw(5) << left << '1' << '2' << '3';
```

produces

```
1     23
```

How can I use the iomanip library to set the field width so that it applies to all elements
producing

```
1     2     3
```

instead of writing setw(5) twice like below:

```
cout << setw(5) << left << '1' << setw(5) << left << '2' << '3';
```

Comment: maybe http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/? just a guess.

Comment: They are at least 3 ways to do it, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248627/setting-width-in-c-output-stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You must use `setw()` before almost every output operation. The problem is that `operator<<` effectively calls `setw(0)` after the output, thus you need to set width again. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) for a full list of operations that reset field width.

Note: `setw` is just a wrapper around [`width()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width), so using the latter won't help.