# How the non-sticky format properties are reset?

Tags: c++, output, output-formatting

Consider the following code:

```
class C{};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const C &) {
    o.fill('!');
    o.width(8);
    return o << 42;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << C{} << '\n';
    std::cout << 42 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

> `!!!!!!42`
>
> `42`

I was expecting `!!!!!!42` twice because I've changed the state of the provided `std::ostream o` calling `fill` and `width` inside the `operator <<`, so I used to think that the fill character and the width setted into the operator would *leak* outside the operator call as if they were sticky properties.

As you can see I don't flush the stream nor re-set the fill character or width so, why (and how) the original behaviour is preserved?

So the question is: How the properties of the `ostream` are setted back to the previous state after the call to my `operator<<` for `class C`?

---

This doesn't bothers me, I'm happy with this behaviour but I want to understand how it works.

Comment: `fill` is sticky. `width` is not. You do not see the `fill` characters because they are not being padded to the (now reset) `width`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which iomanip manipulators are 'sticky'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky)

Comment: And HOW is reseted the `width`?

Comment: This is all very well documented. The above link documents which modifiers are sticky and provides a possible rationale for why `width` is not. If you want to know _how_ it is reset, delve into the code of your compiler's standard library. If you want to make your own override, try looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248627/setting-width-in-c-output-stream

Answer (score 3):

As underscore_d mentioned: `width` isn't sticky. But actually there is no such attribute `stickiness` for the iostream classes and their manipulators.

Though, if width would not have been reset by the previous `<<` operator call, the width would also affect the output of `\n`:

```
std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('!') << 42 << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(10) << std::setfill('!') << 42 << std::setw(10) << '\n';
```

gives

```
!!!!!!!!42
!!!!!!!!42!!!!!!!!!
```

.

Comment: Thank's, but without this example the answer would not have been worth an "answer".