# Reset properties of std::cout for integers or doubles in C++

Tags: c++, cout, iomanip

At various places in my code, I set certain stream properties, such as in `std::cout << fixed << 4.56342;`, in order to manipulate how an `integer` or `double` appears when printed to standard out.  Sometimes during a particular runtime flow, `std::cout` is used *without* any manipulations but the output is inadvertently transformed because of a preceding manipulation.

So, what is the best way to reset all such properties of `std::cout` so that a call to `std::cout<<` will behave precisely as in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // let X be an integer or a double
    std::cout << X;
    return 0;
}
```

---

I see [Effective use of C++ iomanip library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328411/effective-use-of-c-iomanip-library), and it makes sense generally to not use the manipulators directly.  That will be a good strategy going forward.  Still, it would be nice to know how to undo all such manipulations as I describe above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `resetiosflags`:

> ```
> std::cout << std::resetiosflags( std::ios_base::basefield ); // clears integer manipulations
> std::cout << std::resetiosflags( std::ios_base::floatfield  ); // clears floating-point manipulations
> std::cout << std::resetiosflags( std::cout.flags() ); // clears all flags
> ```

Comment: `cout` could also have a `precision` and/or `width` set.  (Though most things that use the `width` also reset it afterward.)

Comment: @aschepler So would `cout.unsetf()` reset something like `std::setprecision(3)`?

Comment: @aschepler But to deal with that I'd surmise that you'd need to save the value of the precision before initially setting it and reset it back when you're done.

Comment: @synaptik It won't. See the comment I wrote above.

Comment: @templateboy Thanks.  I tried the wrong functions and it didn't work, but I never got around to mentioning that here because I decided to stop manipulation cout, and instead write functions that manipulate local stringstreams, which are then returned as strings and passed to cout.  But, like I said, I do want to know how to reset cout, so thanks for updating your solution.

Comment: std::resetiosflags( std::cout.flags() ) does not necessarily clear (or reset to default) all flags. See: http://ideone.com/Etwxky

Comment: @Herbert Yes, it does but in your code the order of evaluation seems to be choosing to run `std::cout << std::restiosflags(...)` first instead of `std::cout << std::showpoint` first. If you partition them into two separate statements they will work: http://ideone.com/t7jKYo

Comment: Where is it stated that the any non-default value is a bit set to one? Otherwise I would not know why std::cout.flags() is a valid flag to reset all non-default options to the default.

Comment: @Herbert Not sure what you mean by "non-default value is a bit set to one". Where do I make that assumption?

Comment: I'm assuming the mask needs to have the bits which need to be reset, set to one. Hence non-default values need to be 1 for std::resetiosflags( std::cout.flags() ) to reset these values.

Comment: @Herbert Why would they need to be 1? The value of a bit in the `fmtflags` bitmask is implementation defined.

Comment: At the very least std::resetiosflags( std::cout.flags() ); is strange, I would expect std::resetiosflags( std::ios_base::allfields  );, but I might malunderstand the meaning of a bitmask.