# Ready to use C++ iomanip wrappers?

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

Since raw use of the [iomanip](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) stream modifiers is a) verbose and b) error prone ([sticky vs. non-sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky), etc.), for user defined types, all that stuff can be hidden in the default `operator<<` ... as [shown here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328411/effective-use-of-c-iomanip-library).

However, when formatting built-in types (even from within a user defined operator), it would be much more convenient (IMHO) to use an approach similar to [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)<sup>(beware C++14)</sup>, where the data is wrapped in a function call that returns a temporary object that sets + resets the appropriate flags.

Essentially, instead of [writing](https://github.com/cppformat/cppformat#iostreams):

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << 1.23456 << "\n";
```

you would hypothetically write:

```
using namespace shorter;
std::cout << precis(2, fixed(1.234556)) << "\n";
```

As the example shows, combination of flags could get tricky and I'm sure the devil is in the details, so I was wondering whether there is any prior art / exiting helper library that tries to address "chevron hell". :-)

- Is there any existing library addressing this?
- What are the technical pitfalls here, if one wants to come up with a set of helpers oneself?

Specifically, this question is not about any kind of "type safe format string" (like Boost.Format offers).

I'm also not asking for a "best" library, I'm asking about *any* library doing this for normal ostreams. (Because I was not able to find any.)

For example, the [write API of C++ Format](http://cppformat.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#write-api) does something like this, but it doesn't do it for std::iostreams, but for the library's "stream" type:

```
MemoryWriter out;
out << pad(hex(0xcafe), 8, '0');
```

Comment: Boost.Format would probably be your friend but it's insanely slow. Just look up any other format library, there are many.  Incidentally, you link to one in your question.

Comment: @MartinBa you'll need to sidestep the pedant crew by rephrasing your question to ask "how do I deal with these problems" instead of "is there a third party library that already deals with them". If there is such a library that someone knows about then they can bring it up.